# Strange behavior in MySQL 8.0.29 when using constraint PRIMARY KEY

Tags: mysql, debian

On a linux server Debian 11, I have MySQL version 8.0.29.
In a SQL file, I have a code for create some tables. In particular, one table has this type of code

```
CREATE TABLE `xxxx` (  
field1 definition, 
field2 definition,  
field3 definition,  
...  
fieldN definition,    
UNIQUE KEY `CODE` (`field1`)  
PRIMARY KEY (`field3`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

When I attempt to import the SQL file, I receive a syntax error near PRIMARY KEY.
After some research (and test), I have changed the code in this way

```
CREATE TABLE `xxxx` (  
field1 definition, 
field2 definition,  
field3 definition,
PRIMARY KEY (`field3`),  
...  
fieldN definition,    
UNIQUE KEY `CODE` (`field1`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

And in this way, the table is created without error.
Why have I this type of error?

Thanks.

Comment: It really helps us to help you, if you show us the **real** code and not some pseudo code. Also if you get an error message **please** always show us ALL of the error, all of it has meaning, even if it means nothing to you

Comment: Hello @RiggsFolly. I cannot post the real code because is a code relate to my work. however, the code is identical. changes only the name of fields (that I cannot post).

Comment: Hello @ErgestBasha. Thanks. I don't have notice this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Separate each table constraint by commas.

WRONG:

```
UNIQUE KEY `CODE` (`field1`)  
PRIMARY KEY (`field3`)
```

RIGHT:

```
UNIQUE KEY `CODE` (`field1`),  
PRIMARY KEY (`field3`)
```